# How to select an item in a list, then select the preceding one

Tags: python, list, replace

I would like to replace an item in a list with another item in the list (to be specific, the item after). I am currently unable to find a procedure to carry out this task though.

Comment: Are you replacing by index or value?

Comment: an example would be better. And also show your attempts.

Comment: Are you swapping the items, or copying? What happens when the selected item to replace is the last item in the list? We really need to see some example input and output.

Comment: @AvinashRaj an example is: myList = [')', 'E'] and I would like to replace ')' with 'E' (items in a text file are being replaced, not inside of the string).

Answer (score 0):

Just switch using indices:

```
your_list[i], your_list[i + 1] = your_list[i + 1], your_list[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have the index, then it's just

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5] 
index = # get the index of the item 
l[index], l[index - 1] = l[index - 1], l[index]
```

Comment: The item after, according to the problem. Otherwise, this is the same answer I provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify your iterable (your list) then you should use a copy: slice notation `[:]` does it.

```
my_list = ['(', 'E']
for i, item in enumerate(my_list[:]):
    if item == '(':
        # replace it with the item next to it
        my_list[i] = my_list[i+1]
```

You should also use a `try` `except` block to catch eventual `KeyError` in the case the item you are looking for is the last on the list.

Answer (score -1):

```
lists = [')', 'E']

for i in lists:
    if i == ')':
        lists[0] = 'E'

print lists
'['E', 'E']'
```

Comment: The list needs to be able to select from the list itself, not by inputting the letter(fixed) into the code, which you have done.